# php file with # symbol not found

Tags: php, file

I've files with name `file_#.pdf` and `index.php`

**Code:**

```
echo "<a href='http://php.loc/file_#.pdf'>Link</a><hr>";
var_dump(file_get_contents("file_#.pdf"));
```

In this case function `file_get_contents()` found the file but when I click to create a link with tag `<a>` in the browser then get error with message:

> **Object not found**

How I can fix this problem and download files with links correctly?

Comment: The # is going to cause all sorts of issues - [Use character # in URL inside file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526313/use-character-in-url-inside-file-name)

Comment: Encode the hash properly... `<a href="http://php.loc/file_%23.pdf">`

Comment: @Phil has any function to encode somithing symbols in php?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/function.urlencode.php